# Opening Gallery faster

Tags: android, button, gallery

Is there anyway to open Gallery faster through android studio? like the way facebook messenger does or whatsapp does? I making my own app and every time i tap the button to open gallery, it takes a few seconds. (I know it't not because of the phone because other apps open gallery really fast). Actually it's not that slow either but i'd really like it if it opened with a blink of an eye. Although I do have have a lot of computation  on the images like resizing and changing orientations in onActivityResult(), but that shouldn't matter should it? btw here is my code for opening the gallery:

```
 public void openGallery(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);

}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The performance will vary depending upon the number of background apps running and memory utilization by them.

Comment: I thought so too but I had so many apps open when I tried to open Gallery through Whatsapp and it still opened it faster than my, with no apps running in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Emulator? If so try Device.
I am using this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

It takes only a second or less to open Gallery.

Comment: No I'm using device too, Samsung S5. Mine takes a second too but I really want it to open really fast. let me try putting this in a thread too.

Comment: I tested the above code on S5 and Galaxy nexus 3, it takes less than a second, opens gallery with blink of an eye.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that, I had a lot of garbage in my code. I cleared that away and not it is working fine.